# Python: Replace All Values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to replace all values in a dictionary, regardless of value, with the integer 1?

Thank you!

Comment: before posting here on SO we all strongly suggest to try something out and eventually post it, because the meaning of this community isn't to provide ready-to-use solutions, but help people learn and understand better their problems :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sure, you can do something like:

```
d = {x: 1 for x in d}
```

That creates a new dictionary `d` that maps every key in `d` (the old one) to `1`.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like this. I just wasn't quite sure what the proper format was, and last time I tried posting something about dictionaries, I was ridiculed; hence the reason that I didn't post my failed attempt here.

Comment: To modify the original dictionary: `for k in d: d[k] = 1`

Comment: Yet another way: `d = d.fromkeys(d, 1)`

Comment: God, that's beautiful.

Comment: As @StevenRumbalski pointed out: This does *not* replace the dictionary *values*, but the whole dictionary. So `d` is a new instance afterwards. If this matters depends on the application.

Answer (score 21):

You can use a dict comprehension (as others have said) to create a new dictionary with the same keys as the old dictionary, or, if you need to do the whole thing in place:

```
for k in d:
    d[k] = 1
```

If you're really fond of 1-liners, you can do it in place using `update`:

```
d.update( (k,1) for k in d )
```

Comment: The update() method takes either a dictionary or an iterable object of tuples. This is simple and sweet. haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {1:2, 2:2,3:2}
a = {x:1 for (x,_) in a.iteritems()}
print a
```

{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}

Comment: surely just `{k:1 for k in a}`... no need to get each item only to throw the value away...

Comment: Note that this does not modify the original dict.  It's not really an issue unless you're planning on encapsulating it in a function:  `def overwrite_dict_values(d, new_value): ...`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. Iterate through every key in the dictionary and set the related value to 1.