# How do you update all the items in a dictionary at once?

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary, and I want to update all the values in the dictionary with a *for loop*. I assume it would go something like this:

```py
fruits = {"apple" : 2, "banana" : 1, "orange" : 4}

for value in fruits:
  value += 2

print(fruits)
```

I expect it to print `{"apple" : 4, "banana" : 3, "orange" : 6}`, but instead it just prints the original list. I am not quite sure how to fix this, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But isn't it throwing any error for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Replace All Values in a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960907/python-replace-all-values-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: The problem is you are iterating through the dictionary's keys, not its values. You need to do ```fruits[value]``` if you want your original code to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```py
fruits = {"apple" : 2, "banana" : 1, "orange" : 4}

for key in fruits:
  fruits[key] += 2

print(fruits) # {"apple" : 4, "banana" : 3, "orange" : 6}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
for i in fruits.keys():
    fruits[i] = fruits[i]+2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like one-liners:

```
fruits = {x: fruits[x]+2 for x in fruits}
```

or use `update`

```
fruits.update((x,fruits[x]+2) for x in fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to iterate through each of them.

```
fruits = {"apple" : 2, "banana" : 1, "orange" : 4}
fruits = {k:v+2 for k,v in fruits.items()}
print (fruits)
```

The output:

Before:

```
{'apple': 2, 'banana': 1, 'orange': 4}
```

After:

```
{'apple': 4, 'banana': 3, 'orange': 6}
```